# Flutter firebase_admob giving unregistered sevice unhandled exception

Tags: flutter, admob

I have built a fairly big flutter app with a large number of screen and folders. In one of the screens, **I have a modal bottom sheet connected to a floating action button. This modal bottom sheet has a download button in which I am trying to add interstitial ads. Now I have included all the firebase_admob function in this bottom sheet and I call the
_initAdmob function in this modal bottom sheet as well**

```
 // TODO: Add _interstitialAd
  InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;

// TODO: Add _isInterstitialAdReady
  bool _isInterstitialAdReady;


// TODO: Implement _loadInterstitialAd()
  void _loadInterstitialAd() {
    _interstitialAd.load();
  }
  Future<void> _initAdMob() {
  // TODO: Initialize AdMob SDK
  return FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: AdManager.appId);
  }

// TODO: Implement _onInterstitialAdEvent()
  void _onInterstitialAdEvent(MobileAdEvent event) {
    switch (event) {
      case MobileAdEvent.loaded:
        _isInterstitialAdReady = true;
        break;
      case MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad:
        _isInterstitialAdReady = false;
        print('Failed to load an interstitial ad');
        break;
      case MobileAdEvent.closed:
        print('ad closed');
        break;
      default:
      // do nothing
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initAdMob();
    _isInterstitialAdReady = false;

    // TODO: Initialize _interstitialAd
    _interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
      adUnitId: AdManager.interstitialAdUnitId,
      listener: _onInterstitialAdEvent,
    );

    _loadInterstitialAd();
    print('ad loaded');
  }
```

this is the code for the button

```
RoundedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (_isInterstitialAdReady) {
                _interstitialAd.show();
              }
              String url = widget.wallpaperModel.src.portrait;
              int location = WallpaperManager
                  .HOME_SCREEN; // or location = WallpaperManager.LOCK_SCREEN;
              var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
              String result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
                  file.path, location);
              print(result);
              location = WallpaperManager.LOCK_SCREEN;
              result = await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
                  file.path, location);
              print(result);
              displayToast(
                  "Both Home screen and lock screen wallpapers are now set");
            },
```

Now I get this stack trace though the app doesn't fully crash this is thrown whenever the modal bottom sheet is opened and this code gets executed.

```
Syncing files to device Mi A3...
Restarted application in 2,493ms.
I/flutter (17161): 200
I/flutter (17161): ad loaded
D/DynamitePackage(17161): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
I/Ads     (17161): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("6438FA1AD0B4EF324042DD164D1AFE44") to get test ads on this device.
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/AudioManager(17161): In isSpeakerphoneOn(), calling application: app.wallpaper.trueaqua.co.wallpaper_app
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/flutter (17161): onAdFailedToLoad: 3
I/Ads     (17161): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter (17161): Failed to load an interstitial ad
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@a986853
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
W/o.wallpaper_ap(17161): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->compareAndSwapObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/flutter (17161): Wallpaper set
I/flutter (17161): Wallpaper set
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@a986853
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(17161): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzji@a986853
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1751)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1776)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:741)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzag(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:245)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzal(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:262)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:336)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:2)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:7)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(17161):     at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.6.0:21)
```

Could you help me with the best approach to load the ads when the button is clicked inside the modal bottom sheet??
Also why is this unbinding error occurring??

This is the admob_helper modal file I have created if anyone is wondering

```
import 'dart:io';

class AdManager {

  static String get appId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }
    else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  static String get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    }
    else {
      throw new UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

}
```

in simple words, there is a warning that I don't understand and how can I use admob with provider hence I will be able to load ads in the beginning and just show them when they need to be shown as I think in the bottom sheet there won't be enough time to load the ad before the button is clicked.